# Error in writing 2 bytes of data to serialport using pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, usbserial

İ want to write 2 byte of data to serial port using pyserial in python. since the pyserial  lets me send 1 byte at one time i writed following code to accomplish my problem but this doesnt seem to work right do you have opinion to help me with this? the code ;

```
import serial                                        # import the module 

ComPort = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')              # open ttyUSB0 

ComPort.baudrate = 9600                              # set Baud rate 
ComPort.bytesize = 8                                 # Number of data bits = 8
ComPort.parity = 'N'                                 # No parity
ComPort.stopbits = 1                                 # Number of Stop bits = 1

position = 324                                       # integer to be send to port

get_bin = lambda x, n: format(x, 'b').zfill(n)       # binary format  

data  = (get_bin(position,16))                       # 16 digit binary format




data_first_part = data[0:8]                          #first 8 digits


data_second_part = data[8:16]                        #second 8 digit


try:


            data1 = bytearray(data_first_part)
            data2 = bytearray(data_second_part)

            No = ComPort.write(data1+data2)
            print data1+data2  
            print data1
            print data2                            

            ComPort.close()                           #Close the Serial port  
except IndexError:
    print "no success"
```

Comment: `this doesnt seem to work right` _How_ doesn't it work right? What do you expect, and how does that differ from what you're experiencing. Are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: at the reciever side i am getting lower byte only. while i want both bytes. on python side i am not getting error @That1Guy